# Lightbox displaying underscores between each image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, lightbox2

I made a website with Lightbox 2 photo gallery. Somehow it displays a "_" (underscore) between each thumbnail image. The image viewer is perfect itself. The thumbnail underscores are haunting me though.

Is there any way to remove the underscores? As you can see there is no underscores in the code.

[image: underscores]

```
<a href="images/swan.jpg" data-lightbox="animals">
    <img height=183 width=183 src="images/swan.jpg">
</a>
<a href="images/bee.jpg" data-lightbox="animals">
    <img height=183 width=183 src="images/bee.jpg">
</a>
<a href="images/deer.jpg" data-lightbox="animals">
    <img height=183 width=183 src="images/deer.jpg">
</a>
<a href="images/frog.jpg" data-lightbox="animals">
    <img height=183 width=183 src="images/frog.jpg">
</a>
```

Comment: Remove all the whitespace between the tags....
`<a href="..."><img src="..."/></a>`
or use css to remove the underline on those links.  It's underlining a space somwhere in your markup.

Comment: could you replicate the same on jsfiddle,http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: I already got it working, thanks to @Archer and Madalina Taina. Appreciate your effort, as I am new to HTML.

Comment: Well, maybe it has only this code in the project. It's his code.

Comment: @GirishVadhel Of course he can add a class if he wants and of course I thought of this and I'm sure he thought too. That was not the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The underscore is one or more underlined space characters. 
Use:

```
a{
text-decoration:none;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I inserted this on the main stylesheet and it fixed the underscores.

Comment: above snippet will solve the problem but it will remove underscores from everywhere you used <a></a> tag.

Comment: @GirishVadhel OP seems aware enough of what he's doing for that not to be an issue.  In the example markup given this is perfectly acceptable.  For all you know, they may want no underlining on links :p

Answer (score 1):

You can also deleted space beetween elements and add margin.

```
.thumbs a {
    display: inline-block;        
}
.thumbs {
    font-size: 0;
}

.thumbs a {
    margin-right: 20px;
}
```

See example - https://jsfiddle.net/52psj7tz/1/

Answer (score 0):

This is may be due to css style applied to  tag from some of the parent css class. So just add one more class or style in css for  tag generated by Lightbox which overrides the style applied to it. This css property will remove underline: `text-decoration: none;'.

```css
.lightbox a{
  text-decoration: none !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="lightbox">
  <a href="images/swan.jpg" data-lightbox="animals">
    <img height=183 width=183 src="images/swan.jpg">
  </a>
  <a href="images/bee.jpg" data-lightbox="animals">
    <img height=183 width=183 src="images/bee.jpg">
  </a>
  <a href="images/deer.jpg" data-lightbox="animals">
    <img height=183 width=183 src="images/deer.jpg">
  </a>
  <a href="images/frog.jpg" data-lightbox="animals">
    <img height=183 width=183 src="images/frog.jpg">
  </a>
</div>
```